# How to display database results from multiple tables in descending order

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a keyword search on my site that allows visitors to search for specific things.  My msysql db has 15 tables and for the search feature I use a UNION ALL  to join them all so visitor can search all the tables simultaneously. The problem is all the results are in ascending order. How do I get the results in descending order.

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1  
WHERE keyword LIKE %s OR id  LIKE %s  

UNION ALL 

SELECT *  
FROM table2  
WHERE keyword LIKE %s OR id  LIKE %s  

UNION ALL 

SELECT *  
FROM table3   
WHERE keyword LIKE %s OR id  LIKE %s
```

Answer (score 3):

In such case I'd suggest you to **normalize the database and put all the keywords in the same table**. **If you separate the keywords according to its type use a column `type` to indicate it**.

The following query will do what you are requiring.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ((SELECT * 
         FROM   table1 
         WHERE  keyword LIKE '%s' 
                 OR id LIKE '%s') 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM   table2 
         WHERE  keyword LIKE '%s' 
                 OR id LIKE '%s') 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM   table3 
         WHERE  keyword LIKE '%s' 
                 OR id LIKE '%s')) AS bigtable 
ORDER  BY `id`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM table1
    WHERE keyword LIKE '%s' OR id  LIKE '%s'    ---notice the quotes
  UNION ALL SELECT .......
  ) AS tmp 
ORDER BY keyword DESC
```

Comment: Yes - for more information, check out the MySQL manual, which has even more examples: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: I've already tried this and I keep getting error messages SELECT *  FROM table1  WHERE keyword LIKE %s OR id  LIKE %s ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: have you tried select col1, col2 rather than select * in your selects?

Comment: @Will: try now, an alias (`tmp`) was missing.